# Netwok on main thread exception in android 4.0

Tags: android

I developed the app That is working fine in before android 4.0.0 versions. But in android 4.0.0 + versions it getting force close. It say network on main thread exception

Comment: Go to www.google.com and search Netwok on main thread exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why your application crashes on `Android versions 3.0` and above, but works fine on `Android 2.x` is because ***HoneyComb*** ***Ice Cream Sandwich*** and **Jelly Bean** are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread. For example, when an Android device running `HoneyComb` or above detects a network access on the UI thread, a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will be thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ExampleActivity}:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The explanation as to why this occurs is well documented on the Android developer's site:

A `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.
Some examples of other operations that `JellyBean`,`ICS`and`HoneyComb` and `` won't allow you to perform on the UI thread are:

1. **Opening a Socket connection (i.e. new Socket()).**
2. **HTTP requests (i.e. HTTPClient and HTTPUrlConnection).**
3. **Attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database.**
4. **Downloading a file (i.e. Downloader.downloadFile()).**

If you are attempting to perform any of these operations on the UI thread, you must wrap them in a worker thread. The easiest way to do this is to use of an `AsyncTask`, which allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. An AsyncTask will perform the blocking operations in a worker thread and will publish the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

Answer (score 1):

"Netwok on main thread exception" Seems self speaking, isn't it?

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            yourNetworkStuff();
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: If i use the Thread for doing that task, it runs in background, It takes some time to process the data from server, before that Activity gets loaded showing empty screen in my app. Is there anyway to show the screen after that thread completes its execution??

Comment: Yes, you can code wathever you want to display something! setContentView (R.layout.emptylayout) and then set your layout!

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says that you are writing your code of connecting to network(url connection) on main thread. You can write Async class which extends AsyncTask. It will execute other thread.