# Always stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, json

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

i have googled a lot of getting json string from url but i think it is time for me to ask this question. Almost all algorithms of this problem is not working for me. Does it really needs to be used with AsyncTask? Im a beginner in android so i do not know much. Please help me. Or if you can provide a better algorithm please do so.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: What error are you facing ?  No error=No help.

Comment: Are you getting any response from server in the form of json?

Comment: Please check my answer sure it will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Reading using BufferedReader object like this way

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line); // Don't use \n this will make your json object invalid
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be an AsyncTask, but it does have to be something other than your main thread (where the UI runs). So you could also use e.g. a thread instead of an AsyncTask.

If you don't, android versions after 4.0 will throw a "NetworkOnMainThread" exception.
See [Netwok on main thread exception in android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896469/netwok-on-main-thread-exception-in-android-4-0) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are requesting a server for response by calling a **HttpPost method** which is **wrong** unless you are **posting** something to server, **Instead** you should have called **HttpGet method** to get something from server
like this

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        String ss = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        System.out.println("response" + ss);
```

**yes** Async task must be used when you are calling a web service because Http calls are not be made on main thread you should use another thread for calling long running operations.

More info on Async task is given in [developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You should use Async task for getting data from server-

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginPage.this, "Please wait",
                "Loading please wait..", true);
        pd.setCancelable(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Constant.URL + "/register.php?name="
                    + userName + "&email=" + userName + "&gcm_regid="
                    + Registration_id);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            System.out.println("***response****" + response);
            String webServiceInfo = "";
            while ((webServiceInfo = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(webServiceInfo);
                Log.d("****jsonObj", jsonObj.toString());

                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

And now call it on you onCreate method.

```
new getData().excute();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its quite difficult to guess your problem as you did not post any logcat. But here i am providing you the code to get the JSON response which i have used in one of my application and which works smoothly for me. I hope it will work for you as well.

```
public static String parseJSON(String p_url) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String json = null;
        try {
            // Create a new HTTP Client
            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Setup the get request
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(PeakAboo.BaseUrl + p_url);
            System.out.println("Request URL--->" + PeakAboo.BaseUrl + p_url);
            // Execute the request in the client
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            // Grab the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            json = reader.readLine();
            System.err.println("JSON Response--->" + json);
            // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // In your production code handle any errors and catch the
            // individual exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```